# Block page from being viewed if not from redirect in ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have created a page that loads a page based on an ID you pass from a previous page. However, I don't want someone to be able to just enter the .aspx page manually into the address bar. I only want the user to be able to view this page if they clicked the button that got them there. I have heard of Document.Referrer, but I am not using any Javascript in my pages and this does not provide enough security. Are there any built-in functions or tricks to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One way to discourage direct navigation is to require POST request and 404 on GET...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at the cross page post:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Specifically you can check for it: (FROM MSDN):

```
if(PreviousPage != null)
{
    if(PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack == true)
    {
         Label1.Text = "Cross-page post.";
    }
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "Not a cross-page post.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your code, but after clicking the button from the previous page, it displayed "Not a cross-page post." Does it matter if the button from the previous .aspx page uses the "Response.Redirect" command to access the next .aspx page?

Comment: yeah you can't use a response redirect.  There is a specific asp.net action which will initiate a cross page post.

Comment: Excellent! Changed my Button's PostBackUrl to the new page and your code works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking `HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer` (`Request.UrlReferrer` on MVC).  If they enter the URL directly it will be null.  If they are sent from another page it will have the referrer URL.

Comment: The problem I'm having with this is that when I check for null, it throws a Null Reference Exception. I'm very confused why since I perform a check for null.

`    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label CheckCrossPage = (Label)LoginView1.FindControl("CheckCrossPage");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("ViewSchedules.aspx");
        }
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath != null)
        {
            CheckCrossPage.Text = "Cross-page post.";
        }
}`

Comment: @titaniumshovel Change it to check for HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer == null

Comment: Thank you, this worked as well as the other poster's code! Sorry, I approved his already, but to all reading, this also works.

Comment: @titaniumshovel That is all that matters!  There are many ways to skin a cat.